# What is the best sutiable way to keep my user's data in Android

Tags: android, facebook, azure, amazon-web-services, parse-platform

I want to add user authorize system in my Android application. At first glance it looks very easy, however; when I start to research, I encountered too many problems. Because every person can download my apk file and can see my auth system code and can send HTTP POST requests from anywhere.

Firstly I founded that link below

http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2013/01/verifying-back-end-calls-from-android.html

It was looked me very complex and I thought that there can be more simple ways that can be fee.

I tried to use [Amazon Cognito](http://aws.amazon.com/cognito/) and completed all login protocols using facebook and google+. Finally I encountered a big frustrating problem. If user would use different login system in different devices, Cognito can not understand that are the same user. I asked this problem in Cognito forums and their offical answer is below.

> We use tokens issued by providers to determine identity. If you login
>   using Facebook on one device and you use Google on another device,
>   there is no way for us to determine that these tokens belong to the
>   same user

then I decided to use [Google Cloud mobile Solutions](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/) but I learned that It is banned in China mainland which My app will also be Chinese.

parse.com is very slightly but It does not have Google plus login.

I haven't only tried Microsoft Azure because Its documentations are very confusing. But If I can be sure that It compeletely works, I would learn everything about Azure.

I am enhuaist to search the best suitable way save my users data on remote server. What is your suggestions ? Which way should I follow ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Why is Cognito not working for you?  There is no identity provider who will ever be able to tell a Facebook user and a Google+ user are the same person.  They are completely separate platforms.  With Cognito, if a user logs in to both Google+ and Facebook on the same device, then it will know they are the same person.  Amazon SNS (Mobile push) can also push to Chinese devices.

Comment: Our applicaiton will have Web version, IOS and Android version. So users will able to see their records on web site even tough They update these records on Android phone. User can log in using facebook on Android device then can log in using Google on web site.  unfortunately cognito can not link these providers. Also app will have developer authorize this means user can logs in 3 different way and Cognito can not links users if a user doesn't log in to both Google+ and Facebook on the same device.
So I am working on Azure, It will links Google+ and Facebook providers separately.

Comment: Hey Mustafa, I understand the problem you are facing.  But Azure will not be able to do this for you (in any secure manner at least).  Remember Google+ and Facebook are totally different companies and systems.  If a user logs in with Facebook.  Suppose the person's name is John Doe and his e-mail is JohnDoe@gmail.com.   Facebook will give you a unique token.   With this how would you auth a Google+ user? You have a name and e-mail.  If someone logs into Google+ with the same e-mail and name, you don't know.  Someone could be trying to steal John Doe's information by faking a Google+ account.

Comment: Hi again. I can not understand this part => "If someone logs into Google+ with the same e-mail and name" how would someone log in the same e-mail address and name ? E-mail adresses are unique, aren't they ?

Comment: Sort of... but they aren't very secure.  Suppose JohnDoe in the example above was using Facebook to login, and then later decides to delete his g-mail account.  Then some attacker re-creates JohnDoe@gmail.com and logs into Google+ using John Doe as his name... Now your app would believe they are the same person and expose all of it's data to the attacker.  This may sound unlikely but celebrities get targeted like this all the time.

Comment: That is very very exceptional statement. But We can find a solution for that. Applications gets user's facebook ID, which is immutable, and saves to server. So App could check the Facebook ID or Google ID. It is very simple.

But I would use Cognito, I have to wait that user login on same device using Google and Facebook if I want to link that accounts. It is very ridiculous. do Big applicaitons - such as Duolingo, Zomato, MyFitnesspal - wait that user login on the same device using different Providers ? No.
Thanks for comments.

Comment: @MustafaOlkun Thanks a lot for your input. Currently the way Amazon Cognito validates the token, it is not guaranteed to have the e-mail address to even make this correlation. I understand this is a perceived pain point for you and we will consider adding this feature as an opt-in feature for the service in the future.

Comment: @BobKinney Thanks for attention about this statement. I hope you would add this feature in Amazon cognito. Because I have to leave Amazon web services. 
Regards.